How Should I Prove there are at least Two Configurations for $9_3$?
Question
Prove that there are at least two different geometric ($9_3$) configurations. To prove that two configurations are different, show that they are different as combinatorial configurations.
Attempt
I have two examples of ($9_3$) configurations:
(1) the Pappus configuration,

(2) the other configuration

I need to show they don’t have the same configuration, but I don’t know how to go about this. Also, I am not sure if all I need is to work with these examples or provide a better approach.
I will appreciate your help.
